# How to customize the tooltip position in a horizontal bar chart using react-chartjs-2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

I am working on a project where I am using the react-chartjs-2 library to create a horizontal bar chart in a React application. However, I am facing some issues while trying to customize the tooltip position to be centered with respect to the dataset. I have tried using the position property within the tooltips object, but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Here is the [DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/horizontal-bar-chart-forked-zzwh27?file=/App.tsx:764-778)

Here is my current configuration:

```js
var options = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: [""],
      datasets: [{
          data: [60, ],
          backgroundColor: ["red", ]
        },
        {
          data: [30],
          backgroundColor: ["blue"]
        },
        {
          data: [73],
          backgroundColor: ["green"]
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      indexAxis: "y",
      elements: {
        bar: {
          borderWidth: 2
        }
      },
      responsive: true,
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          display: false,
        },
        layout: {
          padding: 50,
        },
        scales: {
          x: {
            stacked: true,
            beginAtZero: true,
          },
          y: {
            stacked: true,
            beginAtZero: true,
          }
        }
      }
    }

    const chart = document.getElementById('chart1')
    new Chart(chart, options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<div style="width:500px;height:184px">
  <canvas id="chart1" width="500" height="184"></canvas>
  <div>
```

Here is the result Tooltip:

[image]

Here is expected Tooltip Position:

[image]

I want the tooltip to appear at the center of each dataset, but it still appears on the right side. Any help or guidance on how to achieve this would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!